# How can I get all orders from Shopify API?

Tags: php, shopify, filemaker, shopify-app

I'm Japanese programmer having hard time with Shopify API,
because my shopify site is in Japanese, but the reference is all English.
and not a lot Japanese using Shopify.

I need to get all order data, without downloading CVS file from the site.
I tried use API, but it cant only get 250.

I founded out that there are way to get order data by using scopes, but the version changed and read_all_orders are gone now.

Are there any way to get all orders; and how can I do it?
I use Filemaker in main at work, but also can use PHP, and a bit of c++.

Comment: Is [this](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/get-all-orders-for-a-store/td-p/457768) what you're looking for? Looks like it can only return 250 orders, then you have to ask for the next 250 by adding `&since_id=last-order-id` in the next request, etc., until you get all the orders. It's like pagination and it's probably done this way because there might be people who have millions of orders and it would likely be a significant burden on the system to handle so many at the same time. You're probably expected to cache them, then only get new ones.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I was trying to solve this for few weeks, and you solved it!!! yea, our shop have some orders having same time, so it was hard to solve.

Comment: You can also issue a Bulk download command asking for all orders. You can specify which aspects of orders interest you, and you a get nice download link where the file you download has everything as JSON lines. Much nicer in some ways than paging by 250 at a time.